# redhat + Filesystem error recorded from previous + mount: IO failure

Tags: linux, redhat, kernel, dmesg

we install new physical machine with 10 disks ( except the OS disk )

each disk is actuality hold HDFS file system

after we installed the Linux machine with hadoop kit
we start the datanode and we noticed about many errors from `dmesg`

as:

```
EXT4-fs warning (device sdi): ext4_clear_journal_err:4697: Filesystem error recorded from previous mount: IO failure
EXT4-fs (sdi): warning: mounting fs with errors, running e2fsck is recommended
```

since the errors are on all disk ( we set new 10 disks )

then this is not logical that all disks are bad
what we suspect this is something between the disks and the HW machine

as connectors , motherboard , etc

am I right with my conclusion ?

more details from `dmesg`:

```
[   *CO*] ERST: Error Record Serialization Table (ERST) support is initialized.
[  *CO*] ACPI Error: No handler for Region [SYSI] (ffff883fd24f87e0) [IPMI] (*N47*/evregion-162)
[  *CO*] ACPI Error: Region IPMI (ID=7) has no handler (*N47*/exfldio-305)
[  *CO*] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PMI0._GHL] (Node ffff883fd24de500), AE_NOT_EXIST (*N47*/psparse-536)
[  *CO*] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PMI0._PMC] (Node ffff883fd24de460), AE_NOT_EXIST (*N47*/psparse-536)
[  *CO*] EXT4-fs (sdl): warning: mounting fs with errors, running e2fsck is recommended
[  *CO*] EXT4-fs warning (device sdi): ext4_clear_journal_err:4697: Filesystem error recorded from previous mount: IO failure
[  *CO*] EXT4-fs (sdi): warning: mounting fs with errors, running e2fsck is recommended
[  *CO*] EXT4-fs (sdf): warning: mounting fs with errors, running e2fsck is recommended
[  *CO*] EXT4-fs (sde): warning: mounting fs with errors, running e2fsck is recommended
[  *CO*] EXT4-fs warning (device sdc): ext4_clear_journal_err:4697: Filesystem error recorded from previous mount: IO failure
[  *CO*] EXT4-fs (sdc): warning: mounting fs with errors, running e2fsck is recommended
[  *CO*] EXT4-fs (sdd): warning: mounting fs with errors, running e2fsck is recommended
[  *CO*] EXT4-fs warning (device sdh): ext4_clear_journal_err:4697: Filesystem error recorded from previous mount: IO failure
[  *CO*] EXT4-fs (sdh): warning: mounting fs with errors, running e2fsck is recommended
[  *CO*] EXT4-fs warning (device sdg): ext4_clear_journal_err:4697: Filesystem error recorded from previous mount: IO failure
[  *CO*] EXT4-fs (sdg): warning: mounting fs with errors, running e2fsck is recommended
[  *CO*] EXT4-fs warning (device sdj): ext4_clear_journal_err:4697: Filesystem error recorded from previous mount: IO failure
[  *CO*] EXT4-fs (sdj): warning: mounting fs with errors, running e2fsck is recommended
[  *CO*] EXT4-fs warning (device sdb): ext4_clear_journal_err:4697: Filesystem error recorded from previous mount: IO failure
[  *CO*] EXT4-fs (sdb): warning: mounting fs with errors, running e2fsck is recommended
[  *CO*] EXT4-fs warning (device sda): ext4_clear_journal_err:4697: Filesystem error recorded from previous mount: IO failure
[  *CO*] EXT4-fs (sda): warning: mounting fs with errors, running e2fsck is recommended
[  *CO*] EXT4-fs warning (device sdk): ext4_clear_journal_err:4697: Filesystem error recorded from previous mount: IO failure
[  *CO*] EXT4-fs (sdk): warning: mounting fs with errors, running e2fsck is recommended
```

other fails from the dmesg

```
[   *CO*] ACPI: \_SB_.SCK1.CP2E: failed to get CPU physical ID.
[   *CO*] ACPI: \_SB_.SCK1.CP2F: failed to get CPU physical ID.
[   *CO*] pci 0000:ff*CO*: BAR 2: failed to assign [mem size 0x*N53*]
[   *CO*] pci 0000:ff*CO*: BAR 4: failed to assign [mem size 0x*N53*]
[   *CO*] pci 0000:ff*CO*: BAR 2: failed to assign [mem size 0x*N53*]
[   *CO*] pci 0000:ff*CO*: BAR 4: failed to assign [mem size 0x*N53*]
[   *CO*] pci 0000:ff*CO*: BAR 1: failed to assign [mem size 0x*N54*]
[   *CO*] pci 0000:ff*CO*: BAR 3: failed to assign [mem size 0x*N54*]
[   *CO*] pci 0000:ff*CO*: BAR 5: failed to assign [mem size 0x*N54*]
[   *CO*] pci 0000:ff*CO*: BAR 1: failed to assign [mem size 0x*N54*]
[   *CO*] pci 0000:ff*CO*: BAR 3: failed to assign [mem size 0x*N54*]
[   *CO*] pci 0000:ff*CO*: BAR 5: failed to assign [mem size 0x*N54*]
[   *CO*] pci 0000:7f*CO*: BAR 2: failed to assign [mem size 0x*N53*]
[   *CO*] pci 0000:7f*CO*: BAR 4: failed to assign [mem size 0x*N53*]
[   *CO*] pci 0000:7f*CO*: BAR 2: failed to assign [mem size 0x*N53*]
[   *CO*] pci 0000:7f*CO*: BAR 4: failed to assign [mem size 0x*N53*]
[   *CO*] pci 0000:7f*CO*: BAR 1: failed to assign [mem size 0x*N54*]
[   *CO*] pci 0000:7f*CO*: BAR 3: failed to assign [mem size 0x*N54*]
[   *CO*] pci 0000:7f*CO*: BAR 5: failed to assign [mem size 0x*N54*]
[   *CO*] pci 0000:7f*CO*: BAR 1: failed to assign [mem size 0x*N54*]
[   *CO*] pci 0000:7f*CO*: BAR 3: failed to assign [mem size 0x*N54*]
[   *CO*] pci 0000:7f*CO*: BAR 5: failed to assign [mem size 0x*N54*]
[   *CO*] pci 0000:03*CO*: BAR 6: failed to assign [mem size 0x*N21* pref]
[   *CO*] ioapic: probe of 0000:00*CO* failed with error -22
[   *CO*] ioapic: probe of 0000:80*CO* failed with error -22
[  *CO*] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PMI0._GHL] (Node ffff883fd24de500), AE_NOT_EXIST (*N47*/psparse-536)
[  *CO*] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PMI0._PMC] (Node ffff883fd24de460), AE_NOT_EXIST (*N47*/psparse-536)
[  *CO*] mei_me 0000:00*CO*: initialization failed.
[  *CO*] EXT4-fs warning (device sdi): ext4_clear_journal_err:4697: Filesystem error recorded from previous mount: IO failure
[  *CO*] EXT4-fs warning (device sdc): ext4_clear_journal_err:4697: Filesystem error recorded from previous mount: IO failure
```

Comment: Did you have a power failure?

Comment: @Michael Hampton do you mean failed of electricity?

Comment: Yes, that's the first thing that comes to mind.

Comment: I dont think so ,but I will re-check , in order to resolve this , do you suggest to reboot the machine , or to check the HW or connectors or cable ?

Comment: You should check the filesystems as it recommends.

Comment: do you mean run the -  e2fsck ( when mount point are not mounted ) ?

Comment: other option is to change the 0 to 1 in /etc/fstab , so it will do the same as e2fsck during boot

Comment: Yes, you need to check the filesystems.

Comment: so can we set the /etc/fstab , and change for example from /dev/sdb /data ext4 defaults,noatime 0 0   , to /dev/sdb /data ext4 defaults,noatime 1 1 , so during boot it will repair the disk

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91612/discussion-between-shalom-and-michael-hampton).

Comment: Can you check hardware from IPMI? if all hardware good try to check single bad disk to another machine to check kernel or driver issues.